# FormFlow - Disable switching fields based user text

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service, formflow

I have a question which asks:
Have you ever worked at Google? (YES/NO)

Them the next question ask your current work:
Which company do you currently work for?

If user reply Google, FormFlow will switch back to first question.

How can I disable it?

Comment: Are you using BotBuilder v3 or the FormFlow v4 community package?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Yes, I am using BotBuilder v3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to disable navigation between fields in FormFlow (except perhaps by deactivating the fields you don't want navigated to, but that could introduce its own problems). It's actually possible for the user to specify that they're trying to enter Google as the value for that field rather than the name of another field by putting it in quotes:

[image]

I assume this is not a viable solution because you don't want to have to worry about teaching your user how to use all of FormFlow's functionality. So the best solution here is probably to just make sure none of your fields have Google in their names (or `Describe` attributes). Maybe something like this would be suitable:

```
[Prompt("Have you ever worked at Google? (YES/NO)")]
public bool WasPreviouslyEmployed;

[Prompt("Which company do you currently work for?")]
public string Company;
```

You might be interested in my [FormFlow blog post](https://github.com/v-kydela/BotBlog/blob/master/Blog%20-%20Making%20your%20own%20Prompter.md) if you want some more cool tips.

In addition, I really have to emphasize that Bot Builder v3 is no longer supported. It's recommended that everyone migrate to v4, which does have its own [community version of FormFlow](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/develop/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Dialogs.FormFlow).